# ruby in Rails - mailjet jsonparseError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, mailjet

Good evening community ,
i have a problem,
i am able to send emails with mailjet but i am not able to retrieve or add people to Lists. Everytime i get the following JSON-Parse Error. Do you have any idea, why i get this error?

Example:

```
[1] pry(main)> Mailjet::Listrecipient.all(limit: 0)
```

Why is it even html? When i explicit write (format: :json) i still get this error.
Maybe i just do a stupid error, but atm, i dont see what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

```
JSON::ParserError: 822: unexpected token at 
 '<html>
 <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
 <body bgcolor="white">
 <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
 <hr><center>nginx</center>
 </body>
</html>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove this line in your initializer:
`config.api_version = 'v3.1'`

Because this version is limited to Send API. Hope it helps